# Stuck one to one relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi guys I am new in Laravel
I want your help. Here is my database:

```
user: id, name, surname, email, role

user_informations: id, user_id, status
```

I want the name of all users where status is enable.

What I do is this:

User.php

```
public function information()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserInformation');
    }
```

UserInformation.php

```
 public function guider()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

This is my query:

```
 $users =User::where('role', '2')->information()->get();
```

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::information()

I know my query is wrong, because i ahve not defined anywhere that i want to get all users that have their status 'enable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all users who have 'enable' status and '2' role:

```
$users = User::where('role', '2')->with(['information' => function($query) {
         $query->where('status', 'enable');
}])->get();
```

You can find more details on Laravel docs with `Eager Loading` keyword.

Also you can read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271416/laravel-eager-loading-vs-explicit-join) to learn how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `whereHas()` the first parametr of this method is your **relation** and second one is your callback function

```
$users =User::where('role', '2')->whereHas('information',function($query){
    return $query->where('status','enable')
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use with

```
$users = User::where('role', '2')->with('information')->get();
```

or

```
$users =User::where('role', '2')->get();

foreach($users as $user) {
    dump($user->information);
}
```