# How to merge child key pairs to parents in Laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, key, laravel-models

*Old PHP user here but new to Laravel, I need help(answers or link to related solution)...*

If I have a relation model(or collection, I get confused here)...

```
$data = MyData::with('new_data')->first();
```

resulting with...

```
data = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   new_data: {
     c: 3
   } 
}
```

Is there an easy eloquent or collection function to merge new_data key pairs to the parent data? such that will result to this...

```
data = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   c: 3
}
```

I've tried flatten, flatMap, mapWithKeys, and other examples but failed to get the results I wanted. If there's no easy solution to this, this would be my long approach...

```
$raw_data = MyData::with('new_data')->first();
$data = collect($raw_data)->put('c', $raw_data->new_data->c);
```

*thanks!*

Comment: Use a `join` in eloquent query to perform this. Is there any relation between these two tables?

Comment: yes there is. The data''s table have a new_data_id that points to NewData's ID.

    public function new_data() {
        return $this->belongsTo(NewData::class);
    }

I was using join before but I've read somewhere that "eager loading" is much faster

Comment: Query Builders are pretty fast compared to eloquent if we are talking about multiple joins. You can test the performance like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TJfR1Ta4GU&t=138s .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flatten method.

```
$data = MyData::with('new_data')->first()->flatten();
```

[flatten docu](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatten)

Comment: I don't think flatten works directly with eloquent models but trying collect($data)->flatten(); gives me an array of values without keys. data = [1,2,3]

Answer (score 1):

You can use power of array_walk_recursive to get that result. Lets build our custom function to flatten such models. Try this solution

```
$myData = MyData::with('new_data')->first();

function flattenMyModel($model) {
   $modelArr = $model->toArray();
   $data = [];
   array_walk_recursive($modelArr, function ($item, $key) use(&$data) {
       $data[$key] = $item;
   });
   return $data;
}

$myDataArr = flattenMyModel($myData);

dd($myDataArr);
```

You can easily do it using a query builder or using Model::join();
Here's how I would have done it.

```
$datas = DB::table('my_data as md')
             ->join('new_data as nd','md.id','nd.my_data_id')
             ->selectRaw('md.a,md.b,nd.c')
             ->first();
```

You can see more about eager loading and join here [laravel-eager-loading-vs-explicit-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271416/laravel-eager-loading-vs-explicit-join)